# Return multiple strings from AJAX

Tags: ajax

With AJAX post i'm sending a data and on other page, according to this data i'm retrieving two different column values of mysql database by query. And i need to get back these two different values as a result of AJAX and show in two different inputs.

```
  var mus_barkod = document.getElementById('mus_barkod').value;
  var dataString = "mus_barkod="+mus_barkod; 
    $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "musteri_indir.php", 
    data: dataString, 
    success: function(result){ 

      $("#indirim").val(result.mus_indirim);
      $("#mus_isim").val(result.mus_isim);
```

This is the part of AJAX and below the (OLD) query for fetching data:

```
 $mus_barkod = $_REQUEST['mus_barkod'];

 $mus_cek = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM musteriler WHERE mus_barkod = 
 '".$mus_barkod."' AND sub_id = '".$per_sube."' ");
       while ($mus_al=mysql_fetch_array($mus_cek)){

        $mus_isim   = $mus_al['mus_isim'];
        $mus_indirim= $mus_al['mus_indirim'];   
        }

 $mus_isim1 = 'Kayıtlı Müşteri Değil';
 $mus_indirim1 = '0.00';
 if($mus_barkod == '10' || $mus_barkod == '100090'|| $mus_barkod == 
 '100237')
 {
 echo 
 $mus_indirim,$mus_isim;
 }else{
 echo
 $mus_indirim1,$mus_isim1;  
 }
```

So how can i get back mus_indirim and mus_isim seperately and show in different inputs?
NOTE: Don't mind mysql_, this is an old system. PDO Forever :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by checking my codes more carefully. Here is the result for those need the same solution:

```
  var mus_barkod = document.getElementById('mus_barkod').value;
  var dataString = "mus_barkod="+mus_barkod; 
    $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "musteri_indir.php", 
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "json",  => the little thing i forgot to write :)

    success: function(result){ 

      $("#indirim").val(result.mus_indirim);
      $("#mus_isim").val(result.mus_isim);
```

The Old PHP:

```
 $mus_barkod = $_REQUEST['mus_barkod'];

 $mus_cek = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM musteriler WHERE mus_barkod = 
 '".$mus_barkod."' AND sub_id = '".$per_sube."' ");
       while ($mus_al=mysql_fetch_array($mus_cek)){

        $mus_isim   = $mus_al['mus_isim'];
        $mus_indirim= $mus_al['mus_indirim'];   
       }

 if($mus_barkod == '10' || $mus_barkod == '100090'|| $mus_barkod == 
   '100237')
 {
    echo json_encode(array("mus_indirim" => $mus_indirim, "mus_isim" => 
    $mus_isim));
 }else{
    echo json_encode(array("mus_indirim" => '0.00', "mus_isim" => 'Kayıtlı 
    Müşteri Değil'));
 }
```